# UWP how to update a bound TextBox with changes in selected item of a bound ListView

Tags: data-binding, uwp

I have a UWP Page, containing a form with textboxes and a ListView control. The ListView control is bound to a collection of Products. And I want that the bound textboxes should show the information regarding the product selected in the listview.

```
public class Product: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        private string name;
        public string Name {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (name==value)
                    return;
                name = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Product(int pid, string name)
        {
            ProductID = pid;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML is as below:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="txtProductId" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
             Text="{x:Bind CurrentProduct.ProductID}"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="txtProductName" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
             Text="{x:Bind CurrentProduct.Name}" />

    <ListView x:Name="lstProducts" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ProductList}"
              SelectedItem="{x:Bind CurrentProduct, Mode=TwoWay}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lstDataTemplate}"
              >
    </ListView>
```

The following code executes on Page_Loaded:

```
CurrentProduct = Products[0];
DataContext = CurrentProduct;
```

The ListView is bound to ProductList (Type ObservableCollection). I've noticed by executing the app in single step mode, the value of CurrentProduct is changing, but I think since it is the reference and not the property of the DataContext that changes, the PropertyChanged event is never fired and the TextBox doesn't get updated to show the name of the CurrentProduct.

I don't know how to proceed, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [X:Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) default mode is `OneTime`, in your case, you need to set the mode to `OneWay`.

I made a code sample for your reference:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtProductId" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
         Text="{x:Bind CurrentProduct.ProductID,Mode=OneWay}"/>

<TextBox x:Name="txtProductName" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
         Text="{x:Bind CurrentProduct.Name,Mode=OneWay}" />

<ListView x:Name="lstProducts" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind ProductList}"
          SelectedItem="{x:Bind CurrentProduct, Mode=TwoWay}"
          >
</ListView>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ProductList.Add(new Product(i, "name " + i));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

    private Product _CurrentProduct = new Product(100,"test");

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
    public Product CurrentProduct
    {
        get { return _CurrentProduct; }
        set
        {
            if (_CurrentProduct != value)
            {
                _CurrentProduct = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentProduct");
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name == value)
                return;
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
    public Product(int pid, string name)
    {
        ProductID = pid;
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```